# Push new local project to exsiting remote Git

Tags: git, github, repository, push, git-commit

I create a Git repo and pushed few commits to GitHub. Then I download this project manually (instead of using `git clone`). I started working like with new project. Now I want to push this local project to my existing remote repository. How can I do it?

Comment: Does your manually-downloaded version include a `.git` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the version that you manually downloaded includes a `.git` folder, then the solution is simple:

```
# add / commit if necessary first
git remote add origin <github url>
git push origin master
```

However, my understanding is that [GitHub's zip files don't include the `.git` folder](//stackoverflow.com/a/2751270/2747593), which I assume is what you meant by "manually downloaded".

If you don't have the `.git` folder:

1. Switch to the "real" local Git repo. (If your original repo was on another machine, then clone a new one from GitHub.)
2. Copy all the files from your manually-downloaded version to your local repo.
3. Add and commit:

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "Foo the bar because baz"
   ```

   (You can also split the changes into multiple commits by `git add`ing specific files, and/or using `git add --patch`.)
4. Push:

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

In the future, it's generally better to clone the repo rather than downloading a zip file of its contents. Since Git commits are local by default, you can even make many commits locally without affecting anything on the server.

Comment: thaks It solve my problem! I will use clone in the future:)